# Conditional Formatting based on a different column containing specific text

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I am attempting to set conditional formatting rules on a Google Spreadsheet % Excel.

Specifics:
Column A has a list of names | Column B through I contain a number of points earned for the week labelled above

Current conditions:
In all of columns B through I, there is a format condition in where if the value in the cell is greater than 20, the cell is highlighted green because their goal is to reach 20 points.

Problem:
Some names in column A have the text "(C)" in their cell. The (C) indicates them being a captain for their team. The captains' goals are to reach 10 points BUT ONLY if they are a captain.

Current work attempted:
No matter what I need the cells in Columns B through I to be green if the value is above 20.
I'm attempting to set another condition with a custom formula to have two conditions.

The current formula I have is the following:

```
=AND(isnumber(search("(C)",A)),>=10)
```

Obviously this is not working.
My logic is that the AND() would mean that it will highlight green as long as it meets two conditions

1. The corresponding cell in column A contains text (C)
2. The value of the cell is greater than or equal to 10

Requesting assistance in what I'm doing incorrectly.

Per request:

```
Column A          Column B

Michael (C)          12 
Sarah                24
Elizabeth            15
Jason                20

Erica (C)             2
Chelsea              12
Jacob                24 
Julia                14
```

So in the above columns of A and B, Michael, who is a Captain, would have column B be green because he has over 10 points. However Erica, who is also a captain, does not have 10 points, so her column would not be green.

The other members, Sarah, Jason, and Jacob, would have column B highlighted green because they obtained 20 points. The rest (Elizabeth, Chelsea, Julia) would not be highlighted because they have not reached 20 points.

Comment: What means "Google Spreadsheet % Excel."? (from review)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used two conditional formatting for Column B (Points).

> Please try:
>
> First conditional formatting formula for Captain:

```
 =AND(FIND("(C)";$A2);$B2>=10)
```

> Second conditional formatting formula for Team members:

```
 =$B2>=20
```

[Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/olffK.png)

Hope this will help you. Thanks

Comment: Original post/question has been edited with requested information.